# How to pass the aggregation type in a parameter?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to make a store procedure where I receive (somehow, can be varchar or something else that works) the aggregation function (SUM, MIN, MAX, STD, etc.).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test
    @aggregType varchar(5)
AS BEGIN
    SELECT @aggregType(column1) as column1Aggregated,
           timestamp_local
    FROM test_table
    GROUP BY timestamp_local
    ORDER BY timestamp_local
END
GO
```

Obviously this doesn't work. How can I make it work? Couldn't find any examples of this in the literature.

Thanks!

Comment: This really doesn't seem like a good idea. Anyway, for it to work, you need dynamic SQL

Comment: I would verify the input, but basically dynamic sql: [An Updated "Kitchen Sink" Example - Aaron Bertand](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/) & [The curse and blessings of dynamic SQL - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: Why not? What would be the best practice? Have one procedure for aggregation type (hard to maintain)?

Comment: just perform the aggregation sounds like the better choice, why the need of using an sp?

Comment: this example is simple, but the real store procedure is very complex, so it makes sense to me to be a store procedure (encapsulation). Also I've heard somewhere that even for small store procedures the DB optimizes them by knowing upfront what they do, as an alternative of direct querying all the time.

Comment: but you'll need dynamic SQL or a logic with `IF`s, so it's not like the optimizer will know what the sp do beforehand

Comment: well, with an `IF` it should be able to optimize some branches I guess. I guess I'll use the `IF`. Dynamic SQL seems to be a huge overhead just for this simple trickery.

Comment: Something horrible like `select case when @AggregType = 'AddEmUp' then Sum( Col ) when @AggregType = 'Biggyest' then Max( Col ) ... else 42 end ...` would do something, but the smell is pretty awful. Or get all of the aggregation results in variables and then return the result from a `case` expression. Still awful.

Comment: So, without using dynamic SQL, without an `IF`, but using a SP for encapsulation, what remaining strategies are there?

Comment: Do remember SQL is a special-purpose language, declarative in nature, where calls once made are immutable. Use object-oriented, general-purpose languages (PHP, Python, Java, etc.) to create and call dynamic SQL statements by conditional parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if this looks limited, HABO's sugestion would look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test
    @aggregType varchar(5)
AS BEGIN
    SELECT CASE @aggregType 
            WHEN 'SUM' THEN SUM(column1)
            WHEN 'MIN' THEN MIN(column1) 
            WHEN 'MAX' THEN MAX(column1) 
            WHEN 'AVG' THEN AVG(column1) 
                END as column1Aggregated,
           timestamp_local
    FROM test_table
    GROUP BY timestamp_local
    ORDER BY timestamp_local
END
GO
```

this is not *dynamic* by any means.